# Custom Pagination Page Count Message

Tags: codeigniter

On my controller I am trying to be able to display a message where it counts from 1 **"Your On Page 1"** etc

How ever it does not start of at 1 it starts at 0 **"Your On Page 0"**

```
$message = '';

$message .= '<p>' . sprintf('Your on page %d', ($config['total_rows']) ? (($start - 1) * $config['per_page']) + 1 : 0) . '</p>';
$message .= '<p>Total ( Pages ' . ceil($config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page']) . ' )</p>';

$data['total'] = $message;
```

> Question: How can I make sure that it can count from 1 instead of 0 in message with out effecting the main pagination on controller

[image]

Controller

```
<?php

class Forum extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalog/forum/forum_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function category() {
        $this->document->set_title('Forums');

        $category_id = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        if ($this->input->get('order')) {
            $order = $this->input->get('order');
        } else {
            $order = 'asc';
        }

         if ($this->input->get('sort')) {
            $sort = $this->input->get('sort');
        } else {
            $sort = 'message';
        }

        $url = '';

        if ($this->input->get('sort')) {
            $url .= '?sort=' . $this->input->get('sort');
        }

        if ($this->input->get('order')) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->input->get('order');
        }

        $config["base_url"] = base_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/';
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->forum_model->total_category($category_id);
        $config["per_page"] = 1;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $start = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : '';

        $filter_data = array(
            'limit' => $config["per_page"],
            'start' => $start,
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'sort' => ($this->input->get('sort')) ? $this->input->get('sort') : 'message',
            'order' => ($this->input->get('order')) ? $this->input->get('order') : 'asc'
        );

        $data['threads'] = array();

        $results = $this->forum_model->get_threads_for_forum($filter_data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['threads'][] = array(
                'thread_id' => $result['thread_id'],
                'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                'username' => $result['username'],
                'subject' => $result['subject'],
                'link' => site_url('thread') . '-' . $result['thread_id'],
                'total' => $this->forum_model->total_threads($result['thread_id']),
                'date_created' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result['date_created'])),
                'user_link' => site_url('user') . '-' . $result['user_id']
            );
        }

        $data['back'] = site_url('forum');
        $data['newthread'] = site_url('newthread') . '?fid=' . $category_id;

        $url = '';

        if ($order == 'asc') {
            $url .= '&order=desc';
        } else {
            $url .= '&order=asc';
        }

        if ($this->input->get('per_page')) {
            $url .= '&per_page=' . $this->input->get('per_page');
        }

        $data['thread_message'] = site_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/'. '?sort=message' . $url;
        $data['date_created'] = site_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/'. '?sort=date_created' . $url;

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;

        $total_threads = $this->forum_model->get_total_threads_for_category($category_id);

        $message = '';

        $message .= '<p>' . sprintf('Your on page %d', ($config['total_rows']) ? (($start - 1) * $config['per_page']) + 1 : 0) . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p>Total ( Pages ' . ceil($config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page']) . ' )</p>';

        $data['total'] = $message;

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/footer/index');
        $data['menu'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/menu/index');

        $this->load->view('default/template/forum/forum_thread_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a simple fix had brain fart should of picked it up straight away.

I changed

```
(($start - 1) * $config['per_page']) + 1 : 0)
```

To

```
(($start - 0) * $config['per_page']) + 1 : 0)
```

Comment: You can shorten it with `$start * $config['per_page'] + 1 : 0` since `$start - 0 = $start` and also there is no need for parenthesis since multiplying will take precedence over adding.